# How to return a current function value in a recursive function call

Tags: c++, function, recursion

```
int countdown(int num) 
{
    if (num ==1)
    {
        return 1;}
    else 
    {
        return num + countdown(num-1);}
}
```

I want to know the current value of the function each step .How can i print out the value of countdown function each time num decrease ?
Thanks

Comment: Did you try std:cout << num; on top of the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the value returned by countDown(num-1) each time. 
You can try this.

```
int countdown(int num) 
{
    if (num ==1)
    {
        return 1;}
    else 
    {
        int temp = countDown(num-1); 
        count<< temp<<endl; 
        return num+temp;
}
```

Let me know if this worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

This can do it-

```
int countDown(int num){
    cout<<num<<endl;
    if(num==1)
        return 1;
    else{
        int r= countDown(num-1);
        cout<<"Countdown: "<<r<<endl;
        return num + r;
    }
}
```

each time it recursively calls the countDown function, the first **cout** will show you the value of **num** variable and second **cout** will show you the value of your recursive function after decrement each time.

Comment: tkanks but i mean the value of countdown function each time

Comment: As it is a recursive function you can get the value of the function in recursive order. You can change the else condition by `int r= countDown(num-1);
            cout<<"Countdown: "<<r<<endl;
        return num + r;`